# Seaborn jointplot legend has gives varying marker size when labels dictated by plt.legend()

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend, jointplot

Customising the legend of a Seaborn jointplot seems to provoke the markers in the legend vary in size for no apparent reason (see image).

```
h = sns.jointplot( data = data, x = 'X', y = 'Y', hue = 'Time', palette = cmap) 
plt.legend(title = 't / mins', labels = ['0', '20', '80'], markerscale = 1)
```

[image]

Is there a way to enforce the same marker size?

Expecting all symbols in the legend to be the same size, which does happen if I don't try to customise using plt.legend().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seaborn functions usually combine many matplotlib elements, it usually creates custom legend handles. Such legends don't work well together with `plt.legend()`.  Therefore, to change the legend's properties, such as title, location, etc., seaborn introduced `sns.move_legend()`.  To change the marker size for the legend of the `jointplot`, a marker scale different from `1` would be needed.

Changing labels is not recommended, as the order can be tricky.  It helps to enforce an order via `hue_order=`.  If necessary, one could change the labels by renaming the elements in the hue column.

`sns.jointplot` is a figure-level function, creating a `JointGrid`. You can access the subplot of the main plot via `g.ax_joint`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'X': np.random.normal(0.1, 1, (200, 3)).cumsum(axis=0).ravel(),
                     'Y': np.random.normal(0.1, 1, (200, 3)).cumsum(axis=0).ravel(),
                     'Time': np.repeat([0, 20, 80], 200)})

g = sns.jointplot(data=data, x='X', y='Y', hue='Time', hue_order=[0, 20, 80],
                  palette=['limegreen', 'dodgerblue', 'crimson'])
sns.move_legend(g.ax_joint, title='t / mins', loc='best', markerscale=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.jointplot with changed legend]